# Jboss inbuilt hibernate jar not seen in eclipse, Why ? Q about Libraries best practice for deployment

Tags: java, eclipse, hibernate, maven, jboss

First part of the problem is

Coming from PHP web developing background to Java EE and facing a challenge of shipping libraries with my code. Many jars make the code is too big, I sense this is not the best way to handle my project dependencies so started to use Maven as dependency manager (composer in php). This leaves the question of what best practice if maven is not used. it's better asked below.

Second part

Using application server to learn and test on it which is JBoss EAP 7.0. I see it comes with hibernate core jar file so I think I don't need to download hibernate implementation and import it to my project. Problem is, in eclipse, the classes are not seen even though I imported server library.

Now question looks divided in parts, here are they:

- Aside from using dependency manager like maven, what would be best practice shipping libraries with my code ? Say for open source or coding for business company situation.

Read suggestions about separating the jars alone and importing them using the AS or putting the jars inside the server structure so they are provided by the AS. But I don't know if that's best option.

- About hibernate in JBoss, I imported server libs but can't find hibernate core as in the image

[image: jars provided by JBoss EAP]

so import org.hibernate.SessionFactory for example is not resolved. What would be the solution here ? Shouldn't I **not** import hibernate jars since it's provided by JBoss ? or at least in case of using Maven, it would be with **provided** clause ?

- Final question, derby jars comes with JDK and I need to add them manually inside my project in eclipse to ship them inside in case of deployment. What would be best practice here ? ....  copy the jars to my project, point the project to the location of the jars on my system, using maven with "provided" clause with the pointing or simply use maven to import them using it only.

Note: The code involving hibernate, derby, ejb & logging just for learning and testing, it runs totally fine if I downloaded manually hibernate jars, copied derby jars from JDK folders & used server libraries for ejb & logging.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Concerning the maven part:

You should definelty use maven to manage your project dependecies. It is a standard in the java world. If you want to try something differenct you can use Gradle but maven is simpler.

> Concerning how to ship your application:

When you want to deliver your application, you can package it into a single fat jar that has all the neccesary dependecies. That way you only send one jar, and your application can be started using `java -jar ...`
Take a look at the [maven shade plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/)

> Concerning Hibernate:

Inside you pom.xml you should add a dependency on hibernate. This way the eclipse error will be fixed

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
    <version>5.2.10.Final</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

> Concerning Derby:

You can also add a runtime dependency on derby inside your pom:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.derby</groupId>
    <artifactId>derby</artifactId>
    <version>10.13.1.1</version>
    <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
```

Comment: About Hibernate, adding as dependency in pom.xml will lead to download the jar right ? When packaging, it will be packaged with it right ? Why that approach even though it comes with JBoss EAP anyway ?

Comment: @Anddo updated answer, the hibernate dependecy needs to have scope provided since JBoss EAP contains it. The provided scope is for compile time.